# Vue3 async composable export not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-reactivity

I have a vue 3 composable where I fetch some navigation menus.
Because the content is async the exported values are not there, when I import them in a component, but I would like to be informed, whenever these things are ready.

(using it together with nuxt 3, so you might don't see imports in my code (autoimported).

```js
// composables/useNavigation.js

// global variable for shared state
const navs = reactive({
  main: false,
  footer: false,
})

export const useNavigation = async () => {
  const runTimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
  const endpointMenus = `${runTimeConfig.public.API_URL}/wp-api-menus/v2/menus`
  const { data: menus, pending, error } = await useFetch(endpointMenus)

  Object.keys(navs).forEach(async (key) => {
    const menuID = menus.value.find((m) => m.slug === key)?.ID
    const endpointMenu = `${runTimeConfig.public.API_URL}/wp-api-menus/v2/menus/${menuID}`
    const { data: menu } = await useFetch(endpointMenu)
    navs[key] = menu.value

    console.log('navs.value: ', toRaw(navs))
  })

  return {
    ...toRefs(navs),
    test: toRef(navs.main),
  }
}
```

and in my component I have:

```js
// /pages/[slug].vue

<script setup>
const { main, test } = useNavigation()

console.log('main1: ', main)
console.log('test1: ', test)

watch(
  main,
  (newValue, oldValue) => {
    console.log('newValue: ', newValue)
  },
  { deep: true, immediate: true },
)

const menu = computed(() => {
  console.log('main: ', main)
  return main
})

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('main2: ', main)
  console.log('test2: ', test)
}, 3000)
```

First console log shows both, main and test `undefined`.

Within the time of the timeout I can see that the navs object is properly filled with the results.

After 3s main and footer should be updated.
When I log them the second time they are still undefined.

Also the watcher does not trigger.

What am I missing?
I added the `toRefs` part hoping to keep them reactive, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value for `toRef` is not available because at the time of initialization at `toRef(navs.main)` it has already been unresponsive otherwise `useNavigation` always returns `Promise` so either you have to use `<script setup async>` or skip the startup state like this:

```
// composables/useNavigation.js

// global variable for shared state
const navs = reactive({
  main: false,
  footer: false,
})

export const useNavigation = () => {
  const runTimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()
  const endpointMenus = `${runTimeConfig.public.API_URL}/wp-api-menus/v2/menus`

  async function init() {
    const { data: menus, pending, error } = await useFetch(endpointMenus)

    Object.keys(navs).forEach(async (key) => {
      const menuID = menus.value.find((m) => m.slug === key)?.ID
      const endpointMenu = `${runTimeConfig.public.API_URL}/wp-api-menus/v2/menus/${menuID}`
      const { data: menu } = await useFetch(endpointMenu)
      navs[key] = menu.value

      console.log('navs.value: ', toRaw(navs))
    })
  }

  void init()

  return {
    ...toRefs(navs),
    test: computed(() => navs.main)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but `test` is still not updated. Also I don't think the init call changes anything. So this approach seems to be pretty much the same I had...
Thanks for answering though.

Comment: So basically my main problem is that the return values are undefined (even though some should be `false`) and that they are not updated after they change due to the fetch request...

Comment: Aaah I see, I needed to remove the `async` from the useNavigation function!
I did not see that change and haven't copied your code. Sorry.

Comment: I think it results in this problem though:
`[nitro] [unhandledRejection] Error: [nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably not a Nuxt bug. Find out more at https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports#using-vue-and-nuxt-composables.`

I think it comes from the async in my init function. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: please create another question it is not in this issue. I don't want to be warned by stackoverflow again

Comment: Alright. What do you mean by "warned by stackoverflow"?
I just wanted to mention that this solution is working but probably not the intended way of doing it, because I get a warning...

Comment: it's a different matter from the question it's placeholder for hydration state it's not vue 3's problem